# Alter value in object

Tags: javascript

Writing Javascript, I have an object/class with the following attributes:

```
this.option1Active = null;
this.option2Active = null;
this.option3Active = null;
this.option4Active = null;
```

I would like to set one of those attributes to true based on the parameter `genre`

```
function selectGenre (genre) {
  if (genre === 'option1') {
    this.option1Active = true;
  }

  else if (genre === 'option2') {
    this.option2Active = true;
  }

  else if (genre === 'option3') {
    this.option3Active = true;
  }

  else if (genre === 'option4') {
    this.option4Active = true;
  }
}
```

Though writing if statements is not a sustainable solution.
I'd like to do something like this:

```
function selectGenre (genre) {
  var options = {
    'option1': this.option1Active,
    'option2': this.option2Active,
    'option3': this.option3Active,
    'option4': this.option4Active
  };

  options[genre] = true;
}
```

But that only set `options[index]` to true, not e.g. `this.option1Active`.
Is there a way to change the reference a key of an object points to?

If not, other ways of refactoring the if statements is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can just append `"Active"` to `genre` to get the property itself:

```
function selectGenre (genre) 
{
  var prop = genre + 'Active';

  if (typeof this[prop] != 'undefined') {
      this[prop] = true;
  }
}
```

Though, it would be easier if you could use an array as your property instead, i.e. `this.optionActive[3]` vs. `this.option3Active`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a string for the property name to set on `this`.

```
var genreOptions = {
  'option1': 'option1Active',
  'option2': 'option2Active',
  'option3': 'option3Active',
  'option4': 'option4Active'
};

function selectGenre (genre) {
  this[genreOptions[genre]] = true;
}
```

Comment: +1 ... Had the same idea, why am I always slower than others :)

Comment: I feel like with a name like Zoltán you have no excuse not to be the fastest at everything (:

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want ?

```
var obj = {};
obj.option1Active = null;
obj.option2Active = null;
obj.option3Active = null;
obj.option4Active = null;

var options = {
    option1: 'option1Active',
    option2: 'option2Active',
    option3: 'option3Active',
    option4: 'option4Active'
};

function selectGenre(genre) {
    obj[options[genre]] = true;
}

console.log(obj);
selectGenre('option2');
console.log(obj);
```